# Suggest me an algorithm design with these features

Tags: algorithm-design

I want an algorithm design that works with galois theory and rings of polynomials on finite fields. Can someone suggest me a design that works with these concepts?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What research have you already done?  Why are you asking for these particular constraints?

Comment: For presenting in university

Comment: Such a question is too open-ended for this site (maybe better for chat), but how about elliptic curves over an extension field, like FourQ uses?  Let $p = 2^{127} - 1$, a nice Mersenne prime; note that $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_p$, which makes a nice representation for $\mathbb F_{p^2} \cong \mathbb F_p[i]/(i^2 + 1)$.  FourQ is the curve $E/\mathbb F_{p^2}\colon -x^2 + y^2 = 1 + d x^2 y^2$ for a certain nonsquare $d \in \mathbb F_{p^2}$.  You have Galois theory, polynomials at several levels, nontrivial finite fields.

Answer (score 3):

You almost certainly are looking for [AES](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/fips/197/final/documents/fips-197.pdf).

Comment: Any other algo ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Whirlpool](https://web.archive.org/web/20170817134205/http://www.larc.usp.br:80/~pbarreto/WhirlpoolPage.html) cryptographic hash has those features. It's somewhat related to AES, yet different.